# Entity Framework Core - Child class values null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbset

I have one DBSet for all my child classes -> base class is EventModel. When i try to load all EventUpdateCartModel (One child class from EventModel) with all datas the child datas always null. The base values are available like SettingsModel or AccountModel.

### ** My Question:**

How can i load all datas with the base class DbSet and not with the child class DbSet.

Classes

```
public abstract class EventModel
{

 ... Some Other Datas
 public virtual SettingsModel SettingsModel { get; set; }
 public virtual AccountModel AccountModel { get; set; }
}

public class EventUpdateCartModel : EventModel
{
  public virtual UpdateCartDataModel UpdateCartDatas { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateCartDataModel
{
  public long UpdateCartDataId { get; set; }
  public EventUpdateCartType Action { get; set; }  
}
```

DbSet

```
  public DbSet<EventModel> Events { get; set; }
```

Read Rows

```
 var events = context.Events.ToList();
```

[image: null]

When i add a new DbSet for the child class and try to get the value with this DbSet all values are available.

DbSet

```
 public DbSet<EventUpdateCartModel> Events_UpdateCart{ get; set; }
```

Read Rows

```
var events = context.Events_UpdateCart.ToList();
```

[image: not null]

### ** My Question:**

How can i load all datas with the base class DbSet and not with the child class DbSet.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: You can't. Why is it a problem to declare multiple `DbSet` in your context ?

Comment: It's only a question. It would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to change your query to return an anonymous type that only includes the necessary fields from your model and omit the child DbSet. For example:

```
var events = context.Events_UpdateCart
                .Select(u => new {
                      EventId = u.EventId,
                      EventType = u.EventType
                });
```

Read more on the [EF core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes).